# Xamarin.Forms: firebase auth for google

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication

First exception:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Cannot find the specified file
```

Second Exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=3googleclientid...m&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A38429%2Fauthorize%2F&scope=email%20profile" for authorization. See inner exception for details.
```

here is my code:

```
                 var cr = new PromptCodeReceiver();

        \\ the exception is here AuthorizeAsync()

                var result = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    new ClientSecrets {ClientId = GoogleClientId},
                    new[] {"email", "profile"},
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None);

                if (result.Token.IsExpired(SystemClock.Default))
                {
                    await result.RefreshTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);
                }
```

I am trying to follow the code example from 
https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-authentication-dotnet

I am using their plugin. however I can't understand what is wrong.
I was able to connect to firebase and create a login with email and password. but not with google API.

if I put the address from the exception into chrome this is what i get [image]

Comment: Hi Gilad, I am actually getting the same using that nuget. Did you resolve it at the end?

Comment: Yes. You can't open a browser using this package you must create a dedicated application for each platform.